# Produce ES6 code rather than ES5 code from Babel AST

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to replace all occurrences of `S.<name>(<expr>, <expr>)` in a source file with `S.<name>(<expr>)(<expr>)`. I wrote something with Esprima and Escodegen which handled my simple test case, but failed when I gave it a file containing JSX and other non-standard constructs. I rewrote the code as a Babel plugin:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(babel) {
  return {visitor: {CallExpression: applyOneByOne}};

  function applyOneByOne(path) {
    if (path.node.arguments.length > 1 &&
        path.node.callee.type === 'MemberExpression' &&
        path.node.callee.object.type === 'Identifier' &&
        path.node.callee.object.name === 'S') {
      path.replaceWith (path.node.arguments.reduce (function(expr, arg) {
        return babel.types.callExpression (expr, [arg]);
      }, path.node.callee));
    }
  }
};
```

This works, but Babel produces ES5 output by default. I want to update the ES6 source code itself. Is it possible to produce ES6 code rather than ES5 code from a Babel AST? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong default configuration for babel then. Can you please post your settings and how you invoke babel?

Comment: My goal is to produce a stand-alone script rather than a plugin, so I'd like to avoid relying on __.eslintrc__ if possible. Is it possible to configure Babel in JavaScript instead? I'm currently running `NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/babel --plugins ../../../relative/path/to/plugin.js -- path/to/es6/file.js`.

Comment: You might be looking for the [`--presets` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#using-presets) then. However, according to [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) babel doesn't do anything without being told. Are you sure you don't have a [`.babelrc` file](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `.babelrc` file somewhere? My guess is you should pass `--no-babelrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did indeed have a __.babelrc__ somewhere. I got something working using `--no-babelrc`, `--plugins`, and `--presets`, but the resulting source code differs from the original in many insignificant ways. My Esprima version is better as it preserves formatting. I'll revert to that and edit JSX files by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be controlled by the presets.

The easiest is to use [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) and give it your desired environment presets.

For example,

The code:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log('example');
  }
}
```

When using preset es-2015 [gives](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQCUiKqaWE6IApgHQjoDmZA5EwB5gAtgAdm3CjQC-SSUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=):

```
'use strict';

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var A = function A() {
  _classCallCheck(this, A);

  console.log('example');
};
```

But when using preset es-2016 [gives](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQCUiKqaWE6IApgHQjoDmZA5EwB5gAtgAdm3CjQC-SSUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2016&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=):

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log('example');
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I don't think I'll use Babel after all as preserving formatting is important to me.